# Conditional type in Nim. How to get half unsigned int type from a int function parameter?

Tags: nim-lang

See bellow sample code. Please help. Thanks!
Blow is non working Nim version sample code.

```
macro GetHalfUInt(anyInt : untyped ): untyped =
  when sizeof(anyInt) == 8:
    uint32
  else when sizeof(anyInt) == 4:
    uint16
  else when sizeof(anyInt) == 2:
    uint8


proc getHighBitsAsHalfUInt[AnyInt](x: AnyInt) : GetHalfUInt(AnyInt) =
  result = (x shr (sizeof(AnyInt) * 4)).GetHalfUInt(AnyInt)
```

Below is working C++ code.

```
template<class AnyInt>
struct GetHalfUInt {
    static_assert( std::is_integral_v<AnyInt>, "Must be Int type!");
    using type = std::conditional_t<sizeof(AnyInt) == 8, uint32_t, 
                    std::conditional_t<sizeof(AnyInt) == 4, uint16_t, uint8_t> >;
};

template<class AnyInt>
auto getHighBitsAsHalfUInt(AnyInt x) {
    using Res = typename GetHalfUInt<AnyInt>::type;
    return Res(x >> (sizeof(AnyInt)*4));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here. Macros are not equivalent to C++ templates, macros in Nim are VM operations on AST that can emit a new AST, they're not just code substitution. Secondly Nim's `elif` branch is used for `when` branches. Finally here is a working implementation:

```
template getHalfUInt(anyInt: typedesc[SomeInteger]): untyped =
  when sizeof(anyInt) == 8:
    uint32
  elif sizeof(anyInt) == 4:
    uint16
  elif sizeof(anyInt) == 2:
    uint8
  else:
    # perhaps #{.error: "Cannot get a half integer of a 8 bit int".}
    anyInt
    
proc getHighBitsAsHalfUInt[T: SomeInteger](x: T): auto =
  getHalfUInt(T)(x shr (sizeof(x) * 4))
  
var 
  a = 0xffffff
  aHalf = a.getHighBitsAsHalfUint()
  b = 0xffffi16
  bHalf = b.getHighBitsAsHalfUint()
  c = 0xffffi32
  cHalf = c.getHighBitsAsHalfUint()
echo typeof(aHalf), " ", aHalf
echo typeof(bHalf), " ", bHalf
echo typeof(cHalf), " ", cHalf
```